# Can I create and manage a schema or Database in SQL Server if I am not the Admin of the system?

Tags: sql-server

I am not the Admin of the Laptop provided to me at work.

I want to build a small database of my own on my local machine. I have already installed SQL Server 2019 with the help of IT Admins. But SQL Server is not allowing me to create any table or schema.

Comment: If you installed SQL Server, that would imply you configured who was a `sysadmin` when you created the instance; if you can't create databases that suggests you're not using the `sysadmin` account you created but a different one. You'll likely need to log in as the `sysadmin` account and then provide the `LOGIN` (and/or it's linked `USER`s) the permissions they need. If you want to create tables, and work with the data in the in a specific database, you might want to start with the `db_ddladmin`, `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the IT Admins to login to SQL Management Studio with the system Admin account using Windows authentication and create you a user within SQL Server with the right privileges. :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15
I think they can assign database admin rights to your normal non-admin user.

Comment: Thanks. I asked IT to open SSMS as the Admin. I currently am logged in to SSMS as the Admin. Can you please guide me on how I can add my self as the Admin.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris Glendinning-Smith, I got it done!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment. Glad you got there.

Answer (score 0):

To create/manage database you must have the privileges "ALTER ANY DATABASE" at the login account level, or be a member of the "dbcreator" server role.

There is no need to be sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks @SQLpro. I have managed to log in to SSMS as an Admin. Can you guide me as to how I can give my User the "ALTER ANY DATABASE" Privilege? Or how I can make my self member of the "dbcreator"

Comment: I found the way to add my self to dbcreator. I will log off as Admin and check now. Thanks for the help

Comment: To get a privilege use the GRANT command : GRANT the_privilege TO login_name